# Why am I getting a SPILL error with this formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following formula:

`=IF(DIV_P="ALT",(TEXT(SUMIF(ALT,F3,QTY_R),"#,##0")&" CS / "&TEXT((SUMIF(ALT,F3,QTY_S)),"#,##0")&" P"),(TEXT(SUMIF(DIV_P,F3,QTY_R),"#,##0")&" CS / "&TEXT((SUMIF(DIV_P,F3,QTY_S)),"#,##0")&" P"))`

For some reason, as it is this formula returns a SPILL error.  However, I tried splitting it up into two parts...

`=TEXT((SUMIF(ALT,F3,QTY_R)),"#,##0")&" CS / "&TEXT((SUMIF(ALT,F3,QTY_S)),"#,##0")&" P"`
...and...
`=TEXT(SUMIF(DIV_P,F3,QTY_R),"#,##0")&" CS / "&TEXT((SUMIF(DIV_P,F3,QTY_S)),"#,##0")&" P"`

...and they work as expected individually.  Judging from the official Microsoft Support resource for SPILL errors, there are some possible causes such as running out of memory, version incompatibility, etc.  I'm currently using a public computer, so it is entirely possible there's some cause like that.  I just wanted to make certain I'm not missing something else here with the formula syntax.  Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: @Arctic ,,,, if possible share some sample data or the Worksheet so that we also try the formula,,, common reason is successive cells are not blank ,,,, since U are combining two of the formulas so the results were not getting accommodated within available cells ,,,,, once try this is entirely blank column !!

Comment: @RajeshSinha I'd love to share it, except the data is protected by NDA, so I'd basically need to rebuild a sample worksheet instead.  I can do that but it'd be much easier and faster to do so on my computer, and I'm currently out traveling and only have a Chromebook on me.  Please note that the results are not supposed to spill into multiple cells, it's supposed to output the result into a single cell?  I only broke the formula down into parts for troubleshooting purposes, which worked as expected individually, just not when combined for some reason.

Comment: I know I have some names in the formula, but basically what's going on with this formula is as follows: I have a column that contains a "division code" and a column that contains quantities.  The formula itself is one of several, each having a respective `div_code` cell against which the `div_code` column gets checks, and when matching, it will include the respective `quantity` entry into the running sum.  This should result in total quantities for each `div_code` formula.  In this recent revision, I added in a logic check for any entry in `div_code` that matches as "alt", in which case it...

Comment: ...checks an adjacent cell for a different division code (i.e., a means to bypass the normal division assignment and enter one manually).  The remainder of the formula is for display output formatting (adding suffix "CS" and "P" for cases and pallets), as well as value conversion (cases to pallets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this problem, so I'm just coming here to update with the answer:

Credits and my thanks to Reddit users:

- @BronchitisCat for explaining why the expected output doesn't align with the actual output
- @spinfuzer for the working formulas
- @PaulieThePolarBear for sharing other relevant insights in great detail.
- And anyone else who took the time to contribute to the Reddit post!

The primary issue here is that `SUMIF()` returns a **scalar** value (unrelated note: the aforementioned is true *except* when it's second value is not a single cell or value).  The `IF()` function, on the other hand,  does **not** perform *any* type of aggregation; therefore, when using `IF()` to evaluate some logic against an array, range, named range, etc., the output will instead return each result into a new cell per iteration.

Here are the working formula variants to produce the expected results:

```
=TEXT(SUM((IF(DIV_P<>"ALT",DIV_P,ALT)=F3)*(QTY_R)), "#,##0 \C\S")& " / " &TEXT(SUM((IF(DIV_P<>"ALT",DIV_P,ALT)=F3)*(QTY_S)), "#,##0 \P")
```

Variant that excludes the use of `IF()`:

```
=TEXT((SUMIF(ALT,F3,QTY_R))+SUMIF(DIV_P,F3,QTY_R),"#,##0")&" CS / "&TEXT((SUMIF(ALT,F3,QTY_S)+SUMIF(DIV_P,F3,QTY_S)),"#,##0")&" P"
```